# Rails devise redirecting to sign in when attempting reset or unlock

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Using

```
ruby 1.9.3p448
Rails 3.2.13
devise (2.2.3)
```

When a user follows the link from a password reset email or a unlock account email (devise :recoverable, :lockable) they are redirected first to sign in. I have seen in the logs, this is a 302.

I have modified

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb
```

so that the redirect method has the following added to the top:

```
File.open("/home/myname/fooblah.txt", 'a'){|f| f.puts(caller()); f.puts "########"}
```

So to see where redirect_to is being called. In the caller() chain, no code from the application is calling redirect_to. So I am wondering if there is some bug or quirk which causes this redirect.

Currently a user has to go back to the link in the email and hit it a second time

---

### Update

In .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/controllers/devise/unlocks_controller.rb

```
# GET /resource/unlock?unlock_token=abcdef
def show
  self.resource = resource_class.unlock_access_by_token(params[:unlock_token])
  if resource.errors.empty?
    set_flash_message :notice, :unlocked if is_navigational_format?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_unlock_path_for(resource) }
  else
    respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
  end
end

protected
  # The path used after unlocking the resource
  def after_unlock_path_for(resource)
    new_session_path(resource)
  end
```

... so its default to redirect to root path? But devise.yml says:

```
unlocked: 'Your account was successfully unlocked. You are now signed in.'
```

This seems to be an incongruency in the Devise gem...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have added :authenticate_user! in your application controller and have overridden devise's controllers .

If this is the case you have to add skip_before_filter :authenticate_user! to overridden controllers action

Comment: Thanks, it did not have any effect though! =(

Comment: This worked for me. In my `routes.rb` I had to override the controller for users/unlocks with my own controller in which I only did the following: `class UnlocksController < Devise::UnlocksController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
end`